# Angular 2 not loading component

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular

I am trying out Angular2 and I started with an example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2/angular2_environment.htm)

I can run npm install and npm start without errors, but the Component is not loaded. The selector points to my-app but the content in the tag is never replaced. I end up seeing 'Loading...' in the browser.

All code is directly copied from the sample using copy paste. I have not edited anything at all. I wonder if the sample simply does not work or if this could be something caused by my development environment?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.7.5",
    "typings":"^0.6.8"
  }
}
```

environment_app.component.ts

```
import {Component, View} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app'
})

@View({
  template: '<h2>My First Angular 2 App</h2>'
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

environment_main.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser"
import {AppComponent} from "./environment_app.component"

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}},
        map: { 'app': './angular2/src/app' }
      });
      System.import('app/environment_main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
   <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post a plunker for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion

If you are looking for starting up in Angular try and use angular cli to build your project .

Angular cli link - https://cli.angular.io/ 
create project using

```
ng new my-project
cd my-project
ng serve
```

you can also check my repo if you wish to hosted on gh-pages

Link - https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/

Comment: To clarify, my question is why the problem I described isn't working.

Comment: can you post a plunker for the same

Comment: I haven't used plunker but I went to the site. How do I keep my folder structure the same there as on my local project?

Comment: Even if the structure is not same . Try and copy a existing plunker and they copy ur contents. Did you check cli by any chance?

Comment: I do not see how CLI can get the example working. CLI seems to be more useful for creating projects, I want to know what the problem is. Here is an URL for a plunker where I just pasted copies of the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mdq8AlYTbtfE1HQP4OBc?p=streamer